# How can I parse a JSON object with an empty value in Java?

Tags: json, java-8, null, vert.x

I'm building a test suite to test my Vert.x API that implements a couple of sorting algorithms. One of the test cases that I'd like to cover is to handle null or empty values in the unsorted array:

The request body is a JSON string that I create like this:

`final String json = "{\"arr\": [99, [2, 4, ], [[55]], 0]}";`

Currently I'm parsing the JSON in the request handler using Vert.x JsonObject and JsonArray.

```
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;

private void doBubbleSort(RoutingContext routingContext) {

    JsonObject json = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    JsonArray jsonArray = json.getJsonArray("arr");

    ....

}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
    SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
    io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a value
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 49]
    at io.vertx.core.json.Json.decodeValue(Json.java:172)
    at io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.fromBuffer(JsonObject.java:960)
    at io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.<init>(JsonObject.java:73)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.getBodyAsJson(RoutingContextImpl.java:263)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextDecorator.getBodyAsJson(RoutingContextDecorator.java:123)
    at za.co.offerzen.SortVerticle.doBubbleSort(SortVerticle.java:80)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.BlockingHandlerDecorator.lambda$handle$0(BlockingHandlerDecorator.java:48)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:272)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I parse the request when there is an empty value in the json? Ideally, I only want all the `int` values from the request body and ignore or strip out empty, null or missing values. Do I need to iterate over the request body before parsing it to json, and check whether each value `instanceof int`? Or is there another way?

Apart from `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`, I can get the request body as a `Buffer` or as a `String`

Thanks.

Comment: This json should actually run into an exception/error. This is just not correct json and it's no wonder that it will cause a parser to fail.

Comment: @maio290 okay. that's not really helpful. I'm trying to create a json request with an empty/missing value. So I'm also not surprised that it fails, but I'm looking for another solution, like doing something before parsing.

Comment: You cannot use `routingContext.getBodyAsJson();` if its not a valid json this will throw an exception. Use `routingContext.getBodyAsString()` and parse that string as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really mean that:

> ideally, I only want all the int values from the request body

you can simply do the following:

```
    final String json = "{\"arr\": [99, [2, 4, ], [[55]], 0]}";
    final String regularExpression = "([^\\d])+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
    String[] results = pattern.split(json);
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String result : results) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(result));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }

    }
    for (int number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

This would output:

```
99
2
4
55
0
```

But this really doesn't give a damn about this being a json. It's just extracting numbers from a string.